# Регулярное выражение на вложенность скобок

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Решая очередную задачку, столкнулся с определенной сложностью. Собственно возможно ли составить такой regex, чтобы он мог выискивать парные скобки, ну и собственно при отсутствии парных скобок, выдать сообщение об ошибке. Так же regex проверяет на верность арифметических операций.

Как мой вариант решения заключается в том, чтобы просто отсеять все верное и вытащить в массив все неверные вхождения, т.е.:

```
preg_match_all('/  [()] | [\*\-\+\/]{2,} | [A-Za-z]+ /x', $string, $matches);
```

Пусть оно имеет такой вид:

```
$string = "43+(432)*+(43+20)/65";
```

собственно результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '(' (length=1)
      1 => string ')' (length=1)
      2 => string '*+' (length=2)
      3 => string '(' (length=1)
      4 => string ')' (length=1)
```

Далее просто прохожусь по циклу, считаю кол-во скобок и, если вдруг есть неправильное вхождение, просто выдаем сообщение об ошибке и завершаем код. (при верном кол-ве скобок и правильных данных, типа все окей)

Собственно сам вопрос, а можно ли как-нибудь обойтись без дополнительных проверок с циклами и ограничиться просто регулярным выражением? При этом я читал, что это возможно сделать только через рекурсивный шаблон, но я не вникаю как конкретно его сделать. Если кто-то делал подобные вещи, помогите)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *можно ли как-нибудь обойтись без дополнительных проверок с циклами и ограничиться просто регулярным выражением?*

Regex не предназначен для математических операций. Скорее всего для подобных задач можно искать соответствия для каждого символа отдельно, и потом просто сравнивать результирующие массивы *(без использования циклов)*.

Например, для поиска всех скобок я напишу два шаблона с использованием именованных подмасок, разделяемых альтернативой `|` `(ИЛИ)`. Открывающие скобки будут собраны в массив с ключом `open`, закрывающие - с ключом `clos`. Шаблоны для открывающих и закрывающих скобок будут выглядеть так: `(?<open>\()` и `(?<clos>\))`. В *сборе* они будут записаны так: `(?<open>\()|(?<clos>\))`.

Вместе с php код можно записать так:

```
$str = '43+(432)*+(43+20)/65';

preg_match_all('~(?<open>\()|(?<clos>\))~', $str, $arr);
$arr = array_map('array_filter', $arr);

if ($arr['open'] | $arr['clos']) {
    $k = count($arr['open']) <=> count($arr['clos']);
    $view = [
        'Открывающих скобок меньше!',
        'Количество скобок одинаково!',
        'Закрывающих скобок меньше!'
    ];
    echo $view[++$k]; // Количество скобок одинаково!
} else {
    echo 'Скобки не найдены!';
}
```

Comment: Можете уточнить, (?<open> \( ),  тут знак '?' указывает на то, что отбираем массив ' ( ' скобок? или или вхождение ровно как 1-ой ' ( ' скобки?

Comment: @Глеб это `(?<имя ключа>...)` такой синтаксис именованных подмасок. На месте троеточия располагается необходимый шаблон.